# Nested Marshmallow and Sqlalchemy include children

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow

I have a pivot (postgres)table that relates to 2 table. Using flask-marshmallow and sqlalchemy I want to fetch data from both tables from any of their marshmallow's schema. eg: Table1Schema().dump(table1_object).first: and get the Table1 records inner joined with Table2's data(Many=True):
Below is my current code:

FYI: Im new to flask and the ORM world:

My Models:

```
class Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'permission'
    permission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    object = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, object):
        self.object = object


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    role_name = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=False)
    role_permissions = db.relationship("RolePermission",backref='Role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self,role_name):
        self.role_name = role_name



class RolePermission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role_permission'
    role_permission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.role_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable =False)
    permission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('permission.permission_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable =False)

    def __init__(self,role_id,permission_id):
        self.role_id = role_id
        self.permission_id = permission_id
```

And my Schemas:

```
class RoleSchema(ma.Schema):
    role_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    role_name =  fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.Length(1))
    permissions = fields.Nested('RolePermissionSchema', many=True, only=('permission',))

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('role_id', 'role_name', 'permissions')


class RolePermissionSchema(ma.Schema):
    role_permission_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    role_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    permission_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    role = fields.Nested('ROleSchema', many=False, only=('role_id', 'role_name',))
    permission = fields.Nested('PermissionSchema', many=False, only=('object', 'action',))




class PermissionSchema(ma.Schema):
    permission_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    object = fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.Length(1))
    role_permissions = fields.Nested('RolePermissionSchema', many=True, only=('role_permission_id', 'role_id',))
    class Meta:
        fields = ('object','action','role_permissions',)
```

serializer:

```
 role = Role.query.filter_by(role_name=data['role_name']).filter_by(status=data['status']).first()
role_schema.dump(role).data
```

I want to print a Role o object with the permissions[] object.
However from the above all I am able to get is only the Role content.
Below is the output :

```
{
        "role_name": "user",
        "status": true,
        "role_id": 4
    }
```

How do I get something like this:

```
{
    "role_name": "user",
    "status": true,
    "role_id": 4,
    "permissions":[{
         "object":"user",
         "action":"create"},
          ]
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? For example, `fields.Nested('ROleSchema', many=False, only=('role_id', 'role_name',))` has `ROleSchema` instead of `RoleSchema`. And then backref `Role` instead of `role`

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Yes it is. I changed the two and am still not getting data.

Comment: Also, `permissions` in `RoleSchema` does not correspond to `role_permissions` in `Role`

Comment: @J.J.Hakala ,  Thank you so much.  You can combine the 2 comments together as an answer for me to accept. Also put the concept of Model and Schema field names should be the same for the next dev who might need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some naming issues, indicated here by comment lines `#`.

```python
class Role(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'role'
   role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   role_name = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=False)
   # This backref should probably be named role
   role_permissions = db.relationship("RolePermission",backref='Role', lazy='dynamic')

class RoleSchema(ma.Schema):
    role_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    role_name =  fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.Length(1))
    # This does not correspond to role_permissions in class Role
    permissions = fields.Nested('RolePermissionSchema', many=True, only=('permission',))

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('role_id', 'role_name', 'permissions')

class RolePermissionSchema(ma.Schema):
   role_permission_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
   role_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
   permission_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
   # Should be RoleSchema
   role = fields.Nested('ROleSchema', many=False, only=('role_id', 'role_name',))
   permission = fields.Nested('PermissionSchema', many=False, only=('object', 'action',))
```